# Why can't I install a NuGet package from command line

Tags: nuget

Currently we're evaluating NuGet so I'm an absolute newbie to the subject. Just to get into it, I tried to install a package from command line as most simple task I could imagine:

```
nuget install NUnit
```

Nothing fancy so far. But this is the response I'm getting:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

I already checked, I have access to default package repository:

```
nuget list NUnit
```

That returns a number of packages including the desired `NUnit 2.5.10.11092`.

NuGet version is 1.4.20615.182

Comment: What version of the .NET runtime do you have? You need .NET 4.0 for NUnit and some other packages in NuGet

Comment: .NET 4 Client Profile. Do I need full .NET 4 framework?

Comment: Yes you need the full runtime and libraries for .NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the .NET runtime do you have? You need .NET 4.0 for NUnit and some other packages in NuGet.

Comment: A hint in the NuGet documentation "NuGet.exe Command line requires .NET 4 full version, .NET 4 client profile is NOT sufficient" would be... well... helpful

Comment: I strongly doubt that NUnit 2.5.10 requires .NET 4

Comment: NuGet is what requires it I believe although the new NUnit is in .NET 4.0 (haven't used it in a while)